# OracleDataReader throws exception

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

In my current applicaltion, I need to execute a SQL query, and get the count of the results returned before proceeding. This is my code below:

```
if (GetCount(reader) == 1)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader["field1"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(reader["field2"]);
                }
```

And this is the `GetCount()` method

```
public static int GetCount(OracleDataReader reader)
        {
            int count = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                count++;
            }

            return count;
        }
```

After receiving the count of the results, when it enters the if code block, an exception gets thrown out stating:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."}
```

However, if I do not get the count, it works fine.

I think that since my GetCount function has reader.Read(), I need to somehow reset the reader before reading the values? Honestly, I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Edit;
In the first code block, I get the same exception even if I comment out `reader.Read();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `GetCount()` you've iterated through your reader.  You need to do something with your values before you call the next `reader.Read()` or you'll just lose them.  Basically you're trying to [iterate through your reader twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207698/iterate-twice-through-a-datareader), which you can't do.

You could pass a `DataSet` into `GetCount()` by reference and populate it, then reference the `DataSet` in your main code block.  However, if you do put it into a `DataSet`, you don't really need to count anything yourself, since a `DataSet` has sufficient properties.

Example:

```
myDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

**EDIT**:
Try this

```
OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(yourSQLQuery,yourConnString);
DataSet data = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(data);

if (data.Tables.Count != 0)
{
    if (data.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I pass reader to GetCount by value, does it not make a copy, so that my original reader remains untouched?

Comment: @xbonez the reader being a reference type means that you are sending a copy of the reference by value not a copy of the reader. Thus you are pointing to same reader

Comment: It might be a terrible workaround but after passing reader to GetCount, if I copy it to another Datareader variable and use that to get the count, would it work?

Comment: tried doing that. I'm still getting the same error. I'll try using the dataset approach.

Comment: Your workaround still doesn't work because the DataReader type does not actually contain the data, it just provides a way for you to grab the data from the buffer being filled by your query, otherwise you wouldn't need to do a read() with every record, you would just reference it's location in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a reader, you reached the end, and it would need to be reset to go back to the beginning.

It looks like you don't really care what the count is, just that it has rows.  SO you could just use the HasRows Property.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    Console.WriteLine(reader["field1"]);
    Console.WriteLine(reader["field2"]);
}
```

This would not work if you really need the number of rows, but in this example, it would not matter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.aspx

Comment: That would get the number of columns, not rows.